# You are running `create-react-app` 5.0.0, which is behind the latest release (5.0.1). We no longer support global installation of Create React App

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and have been sitting with this problem for the whole day now, I installed nodejs a few weeks back but earlier updated to newest version as well.  I have tried all the suggestions, clearing cache, deleting 'npm uninstall -g create-react-app

- yarn global remove create-react-app' but nothing works.

If I type
npx create-react-app my-app that error keeps coming up and nothing works.  Please help me

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me

```
npm i create-react-app
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out, thanks

Comment: It might help others if you say how you managed to fix your problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is because the react no longer supports the global installation of create react app. To solve this problem, run these commands:

1- npm uninstall -g create-react-app;

2- npm install -g create-react-app;

that's will upgrade your npx, then run:

npx create-react-app my-app

Hope this solves your problem.